# Databases: Lossless decomposition and natural join

Tags: mysql, database, functional-dependencies, natural-join

The question I'm answering is:

> Consider *R(A,B,C)* with the FD *A --> B*. Give a vaild instance of *r* of *R* such that when we project *r* on relations *R1(A,B)* and *R2(B,C)* and then join *R1* and *R2* again, we do not get the same instance *r*.

I cannot think of a situation in which this will occur. Since B is dependent on A and both tables will join on the B value, wouldn't the natural join always be the same?

Ex.

```
r1 = (1, 4, 6)
r2 = (2, 6, 4)

R1:  A | B     R2:  B | C
    ---|---        ---|---
     1 | 4          4 | 6
     2 | 6          6 | 4

R:  A | B | C
   ---|---|---
    1 | 4 | 6
    2 | 6 | 4
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**As pointed out by @ErwinSmout the first example is incorrect.** <strike>If I understand correctly C doesn't depend on neither A nor B so given r like:</strike>

```
r1 = (1,4,6)
r2 = (1,4,7)

 A | B | C
---|---|---
 1 | 4 | 6
 1 | 4 | 7
 1 | 4 | 6
 1 | 4 | 7
```

We will get doubled rows after joining it back together. Also

multiple A can have the same B so then you would end up with incorrect values.

```
r1 = (1,4,6)
r2 = (2,4,7)

 A | B | C
---|---|---
 1 | 4 | 6
 1 | 4 | 7
 2 | 4 | 6
 2 | 4 | 7
```

Comment: -1 relations cannot have duplicate rows, and ergo a JOIN operation, if it is to be relational, cannot produce a thing holding duplicate rows as its outcome.

Comment: @ErwinSmout Hmm...Good point, the first example is in fact erroneous. But the other one still is okay, right?

Comment: Yes.  I saw that a little bit later after I had typed the same solution.

Comment: @ErwinSmout Edited. Hopefully it won't lead anyone astray now.